# Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead. Why I am getting this error in Meteor

Tags: meteor

```
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.
```

This error is coming in meteor App at run time. It shows error in localhost:3000 so I also don't which file to change.

How to resolve this?

I get this log when the following HTML template is used.

```
<template name="dpVar">
  <h1>variants</h1> 

  <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
    <tbody>
    {{#each variant}}
      {{#each VARIENTS}}
        {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "Text"}}
          <tr>
            <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id={{this.NAME}}>
             </td> 

          </tr>
        {{/if}}

        {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "price"}}
          <tr>
            <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
            <td><input type="text" id={{this.NAME}}></td> 
          </tr>
        {{/if}}

        {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "color"}}
          <tr>
            <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
            <td>
            <div>
              <select>
                <option>Color</option>
                <option>Green</option>
                <option>White</option>
                <option>Red</option>
                <option>Blue</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            </td> 
          </tr>
        {{/if}}

        {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "boolean"}}
          <tr>
            <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
            <td><input type="radio" id={{this.NAME}}></td> 
          </tr>
        {{/if}}

        {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "checkbox"}}
          <tr>
            <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id={{this.NAME}}></td> 
              </tr>
        {{/if}}
        {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "string"}}
          <tr>
            <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
            <td><input type="text" id={{this.NAME}}></td> 
          </tr>
        {{/if}}
        {{#if $eq this.DATATYPE "date"}}
          <tr>
            <td class="center">{{this.NAME}}</td>
            <td><input data-provide="datepicker" type="text" id={{this.NAME}}></td> 
          </tr>
        {{/if}}
      {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <button class="btn btn-success addproduct" id="CreateNewProduct">Create new product</button>   
</template>
```

But I am not sure why it happens here.

Dynamic Localhost file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="__meteor-css__" href="/e0ea4006329cdc3a221d2cd8b53b817dfb1bded8.css">


<script type="text/javascript">__meteor_runtime_config__ = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent("%7B%22meteorRelease%22%3A%22METEOR%401.1.0.2%22%2C%22ROOT_URL%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3018%2F%22%2C%22ROOT_URL_PATH_PREFIX%22%3A%22%22%2C%22appId%22%3A%2215ajde21eyc7cr29ww6p%22%2C%22autoupdateVersion%22%3A%22a0c42be1617fe494b745ead93953bc6dedb0f5fd%22%2C%22autoupdateVersionRefreshable%22%3A%222e3d97ec0e76d08f57e5d3df47d20c6738ba4905%22%2C%22autoupdateVersionCordova%22%3A%22none%22%7D"));</script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meteor.js?43b7958c1598803e94014f27f5f622b0bddc0aaf"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/json.js?e22856eae714c681199eabc5c0710b904b125554"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/base64.js?1a63019243b73298e2964e6d4680f25bca657726"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ejson.js?71047b64b5196348bdbe5fd5eea9ac97a5a9eb14"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/logging.js?07e201b648f16be8435a4f666156995eeda0c750"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/reload.js?da8974b7231dd8c0caccb5f322dcf97329d486d1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/tracker.js?6d0890939291d9780f7e2607ee3af3e7f98a3d9c"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/random.js?fe7b46080c91ce482acf6fc326afbc5b176f0502"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/retry.js?1f1dd2c35d300110fdaba51ce4473583bc3bf031"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/check.js?ac81167b8513b85b926c167bba423981b0c4cf9c"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/id-map.js?9ea6eaae8d74693ce2505a858d9a5e60cf191298"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ordered-dict.js?bf8af2f26c8d96bf8b2e6b407d3ed69f23c2cd37"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/geojson-utils.js?81b79d5cf96d00b4b7a28987debcffb665c17526"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/insecure.js?3dc9d4a2dad55999b5b15a447d57f3d5fb66b290"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/mongo.js?3cfe0c5981c197df33036a37574850f057e934a6"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/autoupdate.js?9a5ea03bf057815385bf569c7acc2c285c005491"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meteor-platform.js?499a2f8522e25820b1153c69a92751ccaae507b3"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/autopublish.js?c3059a78bb200b171099fc4fa1a9345101790ddb"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meteorhacks_aggregate.js?ccb22d98e1b9f4c4077b31f8c35d1a6f2f5a2228"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/jquery.js?dd8bac56f8fd3666d433d2285ae01e52597cc51a"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/twbs_bootstrap.js?e448ccf9152d78f24a6299968e1f39c997a02dbc"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/deps.js?504589e1e9585dec8f9f6094e5a87b22de3783a1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/htmljs.js?567eb96d5d22631c03d6aca6afa4c42f0d1295f2"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/observe-sequence.js?0532a9dd76dd78f543eb4d79a1e429df186d8bde"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/reactive-var.js?20335b7b37165980ddd9f23943b2e5b00aae1cc2"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ui.js?5a663333fd30f8fd913f110e0ef779e84f67c4b8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/reactive-dict.js?1cb61826ceb23464171f17c2191c7e04a9b91508"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/session.js?daf192a7244079d45db32a6fc26ebc3881fc1aa3"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/raix_handlebar-helpers.js?7d3b7f73925dd049e8e445e82fec12071446eebe"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/webapp.js?e1be090051b82f046484dccc2de7d747e50c7328"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/livedata.js?718526445deb4d9baacb6d92c551adea1d36c1e1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/templating.js?376767bb0d2463b3b2615a1b90e77f6b22d39d7b"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/spacebars.js?7bafbe05ec09b6bbb6a3b276537e4995ab298a2f"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/launch-screen.js?495e58cf2465ba553324c68301cc62076b1fda1e"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/global-imports.js?ec6113c4a4c1da16253432438a6de01b494bdab1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/template.a.js?91c59e8a695ea146061daed42c0f82727dbf1a78"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/a.js?4d07dccb999b1199311e4410613330967aed6ccd"></script>



<title>dxpauth</title>
    <!-- end: CLIP-TWO CSS -->
    <!-- start: CSS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
    <link href="client/vendor/select2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="client/vendor/DataTables/css/DT_bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

meteor list

```
autopublish             1.0.3  Publish the entire database to all clients
insecure                1.0.3  Allow all database writes by default
meteor-platform         1.2.2  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your app
meteorhacks:aggregate   1.2.1  Proper MongoDB aggregations support for Meteor
raix:handlebar-helpers  0.2.4  Handlebar helpers
twbs:bootstrap          3.3.4  The most popular front-end framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web
```

Comment: It most likely is coming from one of the packages. Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: updated the package trace, I guess you were asking this only

Comment: I meant the error stack trace, sorry.

Comment: do a meteor list and post the result here. It's likely one of the packages that is using old jquery. Jquery 1.11.0 and earlier used this depreciated method. [Source here](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js)

Comment: updated meteor list in question

Comment: @Bek can you share the path where it is made. i cant find it in /var/log

Comment: When you watch the server logs on terminal on Mac or Command Prompt on Windows, where you executed the "meteor list" command, the error message will be displayed along with the stack trace. Stack trace will inform you the functions that were run before the error occurred.

Comment: no error on terminal

Comment: open your project folder in sublime text & do a search all for the function name (this will search the .meteor folder and thus all your packages).

Comment: Yes I did that, updated in question